# Check if Firestore document exists and return boolean

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I want to make a utility function that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether a firestore document in a collection exists.

Below is what I originally wrote, but it returns a promise instead of a boolean.

```
async function docExists(docName, docId) {
  const docRef = db.collection(docName).doc(docId);

  await docRef.get().then((docSnapshot) => {
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  });
}
```

Is there a way for it to return a boolean, or is this just the wrong way to approach the problem?

Comment: You're returning inside the callback function you're passing to `.then()`, not the `docExists` function. The `docExits` functions returns nothing, but since it's `async`, it returns an empty promise. Replace your if block (which you don't need) with `return docSnapshot.exists;` and put a `return` before the `await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to mix the `await` and `.then` syntax like you have in your question. This should be sufficient:

```
async function docExists(docName, docId) {
  const docRef = db.collection(docName).doc(docId);

  let docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
  
  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, through the use of [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#chaining), you should be able to simply add the `return` keyword before the original `await docRef.get().then(...)` that you have in your question.

Comment: That if block can be replaced with `return docSnapshot.exists;`

Comment: In v9 exists is a function: doc.exists()

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner for that could be:

```
const docExists = async (docName, docId) => (await db.collection(docName).doc(docId).get()).exists
```